# I can't filter the product vendor for orders

Tags: python, django, filter, model, e-commerce

I want special users (vendors) to see their own orders in their django admin. When ever I tried that it filters out the user that ordered the products. Here are the codes.
I connected the vendors in my product model. I can't figure out how to connect vendors with their respective orders.

````py
class Order(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('New', 'New'),
        ('Accepted', 'Accepted'),
        ('Preparing', 'Preparing'),
        ('OnShipping', 'OnShipping'),
        ('Completed', 'Completed'),
        ('Canceled', 'Canceled'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=5, editable=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    phone = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=150)
    city = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)
    country = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)
    total = models.FloatField()
    status=models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=STATUS,default='New')
    ip = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)
    adminnote = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    create_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class OrderProduct(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('New', 'New'),
        ('Accepted', 'Accepted'),
        ('Canceled', 'Canceled'),
    )
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    variant = models.ForeignKey(Variants, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True, null=True) # relation with variant
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    amount = models.FloatField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS, default='New')
    create_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.title

class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['first_name', 'last_name','phone','city','total','status','create_at']
    list_filter = ['status']
    readonly_fields = ('user','address','city','country','phone','first_name','ip', 'last_name','phone','city','total')
    can_delete = False
    inlines = [OrderProductline]

class OrderProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user', 'product','price','quantity','amount']
    list_filter = ['product']

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(product=request.product)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `ModelAdmin` subclass:

```py
class OrderProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user', 'product','price','quantity','amount']
    list_filter = ['product']

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        return super().get_queryset(request).filter(product__user=request.user)
```

Comment: Thank you for reaching out. This shows all orders not respect with their vendors

Comment: @user18532068 Ok, I have edited my answer

Comment: Thank you again. I have a user foreign key in my Product model. Whenever a user posts a product that user will be the vendor of that product. I can't figure out how I can connect that user with the order product. The Product model is also a foreign key in OrderProduct model. the user field in the OrderProduct model is the one who orders the products not the owner of the products

Comment: @user18532068 Ok maybe it's clear to me now. I have edited again my answer